# get back URL of uiwebview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i get the back and forward URL of uiwebview. I wanted the URL so that I can make the back and forward button on my web browser enabled and disabled accordingly

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UIWebView has properties for this purpose, `canGoBack` and `canGoForward`.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

UIWebView contain builting methods for back or forward

just use an IBAction that doest this

```
-(IBAction) back
{

   [myWebView goBack];
}
-(IBAction) forward
{

   [myWebView goForward];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have your buttons disabled initially.

Have your buttons call [webView goBack] and [webView goForward] respectively.

Then add **UIWebViewDelegate** to you class definition and implement the following method:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    [_backButton setEnabled:(webView.canGoBack)];
    [_forwardButton setEnabled:(webView.canGoForward)];
}
```